# How to send a websocket message conditionally?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am using the ws package in javascript and expressjs for my server.

I am building a chat application for my portfolio and initially my idea was to have the client tell the server which chats the user was in (subscribed to) and store them in a `subscriptions` array.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < subscriptions.length; i++) {
        
          wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
            if (json.body.chatId === subscriptions[0][i]){
              client.send(message)
          }
        })
      }
```

This is how I thought to approach it, but the message gets sent to EVERY connected client which is terrible.

The subscriptions object is just an array with the id's of chats the user is in.

How can I send the message only to clients that are in the chat?

Comment: are you using `socket.io`? It uses `rooms` to achieve what you are asking, `A room is an arbitrary channel that sockets can join and leave. It can be used to broadcast events to a subset of clients` https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to maintain a mapping of each client to their subscribed chat IDs. You can use a JavaScript `Map` to achieve this, where the keys are the client objects and the values are arrays of chat IDs they are subscribed to:

```
const subscriptionsMap = new Map();
```

When a client connects to the WebSocket, store their subscription information in the subscriptionsMap. And when a client disconnects, make sure to remove their subscriptions from the map:

```
wss.on('connection', (client) => {
  // Handle client connection

  // Assume `json.body.subscriptions` contains the array of chat IDs the client is subscribed to
  subscriptionsMap.set(client, json.body.subscriptions);

  // Handle client disconnection
  client.on('close', () => {
    subscriptionsMap.delete(client);
    // Perform any necessary cleanup
  });
});
```

Now, when you receive a message that needs to be sent to clients in specific chats, iterate through the connected clients and send the message only to those who are subscribed to the relevant chat IDs:

```
// Assuming `json.body.chatId` contains the chat ID for the message
const chatId = json.body.chatId;

wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
  if (subscriptionsMap.has(client) && subscriptionsMap.get(client).includes(chatId)) {
    client.send(message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, knew i should've used the maps.